# Android 11 media resumption makes second notification

Tags: android, android-mediasession, android-11

I have implemented media resumption to show recent tracks after phone restart.
According to [dev blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html) After tapping play button "static media controls will be swapped with the media controls created from your notification" but for me it is not swapped and I have static media control notification and new media notification created by that.
What could be wrong. How the system know what notification should be swapped?

[image][image]

My code:

```
public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid,
                                 @Nullable Bundle rootHints) {


        //ANDROID 11 playback resumption - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-controls#java
        if (rootHints != null) {
            if (rootHints.getBoolean(BrowserRoot.EXTRA_RECENT)) {
                // Return a tree with a single playable media item for resumption.
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putBoolean(BrowserRoot.EXTRA_RECENT, true);

                KLog.d(clientPackageName + " -> onGetRoot BrowserRoot.EXTRA_RECENT");


                return new BrowserRoot(MEDIA_ID_RECENT, extras);
            }
        }

        

        return new BrowserRoot(MEDIA_ID_ROOT, null);
    }
```

onPlay:

```
  @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();

            CommonOperations.crashLog("mediaSessionCallback onPlay");
            KLog.d("mediaSessionCallback onPlay");

            fakeStartForeground();

            if (realm == null || realm.isClosed()) {
                initRealm();
            }

            if (playlist != null && currentEpisode != null) {
                play();
            } else {
                List<Episode> unfinished = UserDataManager.getInstance(URLPlayerService.this)
                        .getUnfinishedEpisodesData();
                if (unfinished != null && unfinished.size() > 0) {
                    EpisodePlaylist list = new EpisodePlaylist(unfinished);
                    URLPlayerService.startActionSetPlaylist(URLPlayerService.this, list, 0, true);
                } else {
                    KLog.w("stopself");
                    if (!wasForegroudStart) {
                        fakeStartForeground();
                    }
                    CommonOperations
                            .crashLog("stopself #" + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
                    stopSelf();
                    cancelNotification();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed my issue. There is probably some bud in Android 11 and when I used startForeground with not MediaStyle notification before using MediaStyle notification the problem occurs very often. Even without it I get double notifications from time to time.

I have ended up with using PlayerNotificationManager from ExoPlayer extension.